# Swift Codable - decode nested dictionary

Tags: swift, serialization, swift4, codable

Lets say I have a dictionary like this:

```
{"user_data":{"id":3,"name":"Damian D","email":"aaa@aaa.pl"},"status":true}
```

How can I use `Codable` protocol to decode just `user_data` into such `struct`:

```
struct User: Codable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case username = "name"
        case email
    }

    let id:       Int
    let username: String
    let email:    String
}
```

Do I need to convert this sub dictionary into Data, or is there a easier way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you create nested Coding Keys you will accomplish decoding the response using only one data model.

Given the following JSON response:

```
let data = """
{
    "user_data": {
        "id":3,
        "name":"Damian D",
        "email":"aaa@aaa.pl"

    },
    "status":true
}
""".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
```

and the following data model:

```
public struct User: Decodable {

    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var email: String

    // MARK: - Codable
    private enum RootCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case userData = "user_data"

        enum NestedCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case id
            case name
            case email
        }
    }

    required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let rootContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: RootCodingKeys.self)
        let userDataContainer = try rootContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: RootCodingKeys.NestedCodingKeys.self, forKey: .userData)

        self.id = try userDataContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try userDataContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.email = try userDataContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .email)
    }
}
```

You can decode your response into a single object:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let user = try? decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new struct that has a `userData` member of type `User`.

```
struct Response: Codable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userData = "user_data"
        case status
    }

    let userData: User
    let status:   Bool
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think this is good enough in my example.

Comment: Hey Mike, can you provide the full class answer? I'm having trouble pairing the pieces :)

Comment: Hi Roi, this article should help; https://hackernoon.com/everything-about-codable-in-swift-4-97d0e18a2999